# Reset google chrome country setting

Tags: google-chrome

Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)

After using a vpn for a day to test it, Chrome has changed my default location to brazil and no amount of clearing caches seems to help.

EDIT:

What I've tried:

- Clear Cookies
- Clear Caches

Comment: Are you logged in to Chrome? Did you try clearing your cookies?

Comment: @Arjan yep, tried that

Comment: Please add those details to your question. And anything else you tried. Also, your comment did not answer my first question.